# How to reset a button/label in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, uibutton

I am creating an app where you press a button and then it gives you a tally in a label. I then have a button to clear out the information.

Example. If I press buttonTwo it will add "1" to the label "labelTwo". A user pressed the button 5 times and the labelTwo will show "5". I click "clearButton" and it clears it out.

My issue is that after clearing, if I press button two, labelTwo will not restart at "1" but continue at "6" as if I never cleared it.

Thank you

```
 - (IBAction)buttonFour:(id)sender {
    self.four += 1;
    [self.labelFour setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.four]];
}

- (IBAction)buttonThree:(id)sender {
    self.three += 1;
    [self.labelThree setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.three]];
}

- (IBAction)buttonTwo:(id)sender {
    self.two += 1;
    [self.labelTwo setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.two]];
}

- (IBAction)buttonOne:(id)sender {
    self.one += 1;
    [self.labelOne setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.one]];
}

- (IBAction)clearButton:(id)sender {
    self.clear = 0;
    [self.clearFour setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.clear]];
    self.clear = 0;
    [self.clearThree setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.clear]];
    self.clear = 0;
    [self.clearTwo setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.clear]];
    self.clear = 0;
    [self.clearOne setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.clear]];
    self.clear = 0;
    [self.clearTotal setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.clear]];
}

- (IBAction)totalOne:(id)sender {
    self.oneTotal +=1; [self.total setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.oneTotal]];
}

- (IBAction)totalTwo:(id)sender {
    self.oneTotal +=1; [self.total setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.oneTotal]];
}

- (IBAction)totalThree:(id)sender {
    self.oneTotal +=1; [self.total setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.oneTotal]];
}

- (IBAction)totalFour:(id)sender {
    self.oneTotal +=1; [self.total setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.oneTotal]];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the value of `self.two` back to zero in the `clearButton:` method. Add this to your `clearButton:` method:

```
self.one = 0;
self.two = 0;
self.three = 0;
self.four = 0;
self.five = 0;
```